# How do I print all the occurrences of the greatest two integers in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, find-occurrences

I am trying to print the occurrences of the two highest integers in an integer array but the output keeps coming out with the top three.

```
Integer[] scores = {4,4,4,6,6,4,2,3};
        Arrays.sort(scores, Collections.reverseOrder());

        int flag = 0;
        System.out.println(scores[0]);
        int first = scores[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < scores.length; i++) {;
            if(first == scores[i]) {
                System.out.println(scores[i]);
            }else {
                first = scores[i];
                flag++;
                System.out.println(scores[i]);
            }
            if(flag == 2) {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Is there a better way to have them print? They are currently printing out as 6 6 4 4 4 4 3.
The correct output should be 6 6 4 4 4 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `System.out.println(scores[i])` after you increment the flag to be 2. You shouldn't be printing when this is the third number in the list.

I've changed/simplified the code as

```
int flag = 0;
int first = scores[0];
for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
    if(first != scores[i]) { //Encountering second number
        first = scores[i];
        flag++;
    }
    if(flag == 2) { //If already seen three numbers, break
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(scores[i]); //Good to print it
}
```

It is more intuitive to rename `first` as `number` or something else as it can hold the first or the second number.

Answer (score 0):

Integer[] scores = {4,4,4,6,6,4,2,3};
        Arrays.sort(scores, Collections.reverseOrder());

```
    int flag = 0;
    System.out.println(scores[0]);
    int first = scores[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < scores.length; i++) {;
        if(first == scores[i]) {
            System.out.println(scores[i]);
        }else if(first != scores[i] && flag == 0) {//you need to change this 
            first = scores[i];
            flag++;
            System.out.println(scores[i]);
        }else{ // if you dont want to traverse list after getting desired output
            break;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer an `int[]` over `Integer[]`, and iterate the sorted array backwards. You actually don't need an `else` here, simply check that you aren't at the end of the array - and if you aren't check that the current score differs from the next (since we're iterating backwards). You only need to test `flag` when that condition is met (and `break` after the second change). Like,

```
int[] scores = { 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 4, 2, 3 };
Arrays.sort(scores);
for (int i = scores.length - 1, flag = 0; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (i != scores.length - 1 && scores[i] != scores[i + 1]) {
        flag++;
        if (flag >= 2) {
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(scores[i]);
}
```